# SAS - I would like to count characteristics across variables

Tags: sas, counting

I have a data set which essence is the following

```
data have;
input Name $ ab gh vz iz jh pq ch km eo lk;
datalines;
adam 7 8 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
bob 0 1 0 3 4 6 0 1 6 0
clint 0 0 0 5 4 3 1 0 0 2
;
run;
```

Now I would like to count how many times I have a number greater than zero in the variables `iz`, `jh`, `ch`and `km`. The result should look like this

```
/* want
Name  ab gh vz iz jh pq ch km eo lk count_of_iz_jh_ch_km
adam  7   8  7  0  2  3  0  0  0  0  1
bob   0   1  0  3  0  6  0  1  6  0  2
clint 5   0  0  5  4  3  1  2  0  2  4
*/
```

I would greatly appreciate any help since I wasn't successful searching the internet for a solution.

Gerit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will initialize the required variables from `have` into an array called `vars`, then for each row, count every time one of these variables is > 0.

```
data want;
    set have;
    array vars[*] iz jh ch km;

    count_of_iz_ch_km = 0;

    do i = 1 to dim(vars);
        if(vars[i] > 0) then count_of_iz_ch_km+1;
    end;

    drop i;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you. Works nicely.